# Apple devices couldn't be connected or even detected, how can I solve this please?

Tags: devices, apple

I'm trying to do a backup of my apple device, but it won't go ahead.
I'm using `Tunesviewer`, but it does not even recognize my Apple devices.
Could someone please help me?